# Compiling java code with non java extension file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am working on a project in which there are jsp files and some files with extension .jsps. And these files only include java snippets in form of <% %> and javascript code. And this .jsps file is included in jsp file. For compiling, eclipse is just ignoring .jsps files. And I want to compile all the files using eclipse version 3.4.1. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Regards

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is ask your app server to pre-compile all the JSPs.  Each servlet/JSP engine will do it differently (e.g., WebLogic versus Tomcat), so you should be using the JSP compiler for the app server you're going to deploy to.

You can usually find Ant tasks to accomplish this.  I don't think it's a job for Eclipse, unless you can find a plug-in for your app server.

Comment: Right. I think the JSP compiler is somewhat tied to the implementation of the JSP runtime by a particular appserver, so you should let the app server do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. Actually, I solved the issue by using ANT through eclipse. And ANT file was already building the project, but outside of eclipse. Now, I used build.xml file in eclipse and it worked :)